# proving $\forall n \in Z,$ : ($\exists a,b \in Z$ $n=4a+5b$) $\implies$ ($\exists a,b \in Z$ $n^2 = 5a+4b-1$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove $\forall n \in Z,$ : ($\exists a,b \in Z$ $n=4a+5b$) $\implies$ ($\exists a,b \in Z$ $n^2 = 5a+4b-1$)

Which proof technique would work the best?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97457/discussion-on-question-by-ph-quiett-proving-forall-n-in-z-exists-a-b).

Answer (score 2):

Accumulating selected comments into an answer . . .

Fix $n\in Z$.

Let $P,Q$ be the statements
\begin{align*}
P&=\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\;(n=4a+5b)\\[4pt]
Q&=\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\;(n^2=5a+4b-1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
The goal is to prove $P\implies Q$.

A key observation is that the variables $a,b$ in the statement $P$ are independent of the variables $a,b$ in the statement $Q$.

For example, leaving $P$ unchanged, if we change the variable names in $Q$ to $a',b'$ instead of $a,b$, the new statement $Q'$ would be equivalent to $Q$.

Next, recall that a statement of the form $P\implies Q$ is true *unless* $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.

Typically, to directly prove a statement of the form $P\implies Q$, one starts by assuming $P$, and then, based on that assumption, one proceeds to prove $Q$.

But if we can prove $Q$ without assuming $P$, that already suffices to prove $P\implies Q$.

And in fact, as discussed in the comments, $Q$ is true, all by itself.

I outlined one way to prove $Q$, and Bill Dubuque outlined another.

$\bullet\;\;$My version:

  I'll assume you have Bezout's theorem: If
  $A,B\in\mathbb{Z}$
  are such that
  $\gcd(A,B)=1$
  , the equation
  $AX+BY=1$
  has a solution in integers
  $X,Y$
  .
  Noting that if $AX+BY=1$, then $A(NX)+B(NY)=N$, we get the corollary: If $A,B\in\mathbb{Z}$ are such that $\gcd(A,B)=1$, then for all $N\in\mathbb{Z}$, the equation $AX+BY=N$ has a solution in integers $X,Y$.

  As a consequence, since $\gcd(5,4)=1$, every integer is expressible as $5a+4b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

  From that, it follows easily that every integer is expressible as $5a+4b-1$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $n^2$ is so expressible. Therefore $Q$ is true.

$\bullet\;\;$Bill Dubuque's version (admittedly simpler):

  From the identity
  $m=5(m)+4(-m)$
  , it follows that every integer can be expressed as
  $5a+4b$
  for some
  $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$
  . In particular,
  $n^2+1$
  is so expressible. Therefore
  $Q$
  is true.

Comment: +1 for collecting everything into a cohesive answer.